# Problemas al hacer update en GridView con asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, ms-access

Estoy tratando de realizer un update con la function de `RowUpdating` del mismo `Gridview`por al darle en `update`, este tira un error y no continua la ejecucion, he probado de todo, y he buscado la solucion en muchos foros y solo no quiere funcionar... estoy usando una base de datos en Access

Este es mi codigo:

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            //Code display data
            string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
                {

                    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();

                    string id = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string who = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string payrol = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string ou = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string pool = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string team = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
                    string rol = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;

                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET who = '" + who + "', payroll_number = '" + payrol + "',name = '" + name + "', ou = '" + ou + "', pool = '" + pool + "', team = '" + team + "', rol_id = '" + rol + "' WHERE id = '" + id + "'";

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                    connection.Close();
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");

                }
            }
        }

        protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
```

y asi es como tengo el GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True"
                            onrowcancelingedit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" onrowediting="GridView2_RowEditing" 
                            onrowupdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging" >
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Who">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_who" type="String" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("who") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("who") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payroll Number">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_pay" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payroll_number") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payroll_number") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_name" type="String" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OU">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_ou" type="String" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ou") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ou") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pool">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_pool" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pool") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pool") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_team" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("team") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("team") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rol">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Tgv_rol" type="Int32" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rol_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rol_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

y este es el error que tira en la primer linea donde esta el `id = ((TextBox...))`

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema evidentemente es que el primer control de tú celda (índice 0) no es un `TextBox`, debes asegurarte de encontrar el objeto correcto.

Primero asegura que cada uno de tus `TextBox` dentro de la Fila tengan un nombre único, Ej. txtid, txtwho, etc

Luego, cambia las líneas de código donde realizas la obtención de los valores por lo siguiente

```
string id = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1")).Text;
string who = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_who")).Text;
string payrol = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_pay")).Text;
string name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_name")).Text;
string ou = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_ou")).Text;
string pool = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_pool")).Text;
string team = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_team")).Text;
string rol = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_rol")).Text;
```

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste pero al momento de entrar al `ExecuteNonQuery` fallo y me mando esta excepcion `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos eso es una pregunta diferente. Tiene que ver con que probablemente tu campo `id` en la base de datos sea un `int` y tu le estas pasando un `string`. Deberias usar consultas parametrizadas y solucionarias estos errores y la posibilidad de sql injection

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos eso significa que la respuesta de Weimar ha solucionado el problema expuesto, y el problema es que ahora tienes otro problema. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada ya que eso te ha ayudado a que no te salga el error.